# How to write a get method for data with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two entities connected by a many-to-many relationship.

First class:

```
 public class Movie
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }

     public List<MovieActor> MovieActor { get; set; }
 }
```

Second class:

```
 public class Actor
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public List<MovieActor> MovieActor { get; set; }
 }
```

And relationship (many to many):

```
public class MovieActor
 {
     public int MovieId { get; set; }
     public Movie Movie { get; set; }

     public int ActorId { get; set; }
     public Actor Actor { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to write the `IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies(int actorId)` method, which takes the actor's id as the parameter. I would like the method to return a list of movies in which an actor with the given Id plays. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you can do something like this

```
 public IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies(int actorId)
 {
     var result = await _context.Actor.Where(x => x.Id == actorId).
                                          Include(x => x.MovieActor).ThenInclude(x => x.Movie).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        
     var movies = result.MovieActor.select(x => x.Movie).Tolist();
     return movies
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the MovieActor class

Change to:

```
public class Movie
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }

     public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
 }

 public class Actor
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you can select the Actor and you have the list of Movies as a property on the actor.

Comment: In the problem I am facing, I cannot change the structure of the entity. What I have given here is just a simplified example of the problem I am facing. The actor and movie table are more extensive, and the relationship table also has several additional fields.